# Bash script for displaying / pipeing two columns

Tags: python, bash

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                         
while IFS='"' read -r a ip c
do
    echo "ip: $ip"
    whois "$ip" | grep descr
done < <(sort -nr $1 | head -10)
```

It takes the second columen out of this file:

```
2132  "291.2.1.42"
5645  "231.26.12.77"
..
```

And greps the description field out of a whois request like this:

```
ip: 62.178.124.23
descr:          UPC Telekabel
descr:          DHCP Range
```

I now need also the first column out of my source file to be extracted and be displayed alongside the IP adress, like this:

```
Views: 72123    ip: 62.178.124.23
descr:          UPC Telekabel
descr:          DHCP Range
```

How to achieve? Or should I switch to python in order to be able to tackle this level of complexity?

Comment: That's awesome, post it as answer and receive points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                         
while IFS='"' read -r a ip c
do
    printf "Views: $a\tip: $ip\n"
    whois "$ip" | grep descr
done < <(sort -nr $1 | head -10)
```

Comment: `printf` format strings should basically always be single quoted (or unquoted if they don't need any quoting) and shouldn't contain variable expansions. So `printf 'Views: %s\tip: %s\n' "$a" "$ip"` in this case.

Comment: The point was that I did notunderstand "read -r a ip c", now I do. :)